# Oracle: How to find in a tree

Tags: oracle

Sorry for my English.

Is table `Category`:

```
ID
PID
name
```

And hierarchy:

- Category 1

  - Category 2

    - **Category 3**

      - Category 4
      - Category 5
  - **Category 3**

    - Category 7
    - Category 8

Name of category may be repeated. How do I can to find all children on request: "Category 2 and Category 3" for oracle?

The result should be:

- Category 2

  - Category 3

    - Category 4
    - Category 5

**== Updated ==**

I need to find by name "Category 2 AND Category 3", because name of category may be repeated!

Comment: CONNECT BY PRIOR but i do not understand how to find Category 2 and Category 3 in a tree branch.

Comment: It's really not about the tree branches.  Look at your data as if it's just a flat table and then try to pick a specific 'Category 3'.  If all you have is the name you will not be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of assumptions.  PID is the parent id of the current record and you know the ID of category 2.

I will use 245 as the id of category 2 in this example.  If you don't have a way to get a unique id for the starting  category, that is a different problem all together that has to be solved in your data.

(I gave a similar answer to another question yesterday doing a bottom up query.  The difference between bottom up and top down is the order of the col1 = col2 in the connect by prior statement.)

Use a [hierarchical query](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2038).

```
select  Lpad(Name,Length(Name) + LEVEL * 10 - 10,'-') Name 
  from Category
 start with id = 245
connect by prior id = pid;
```

Here is an [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0c6b/6).

============Edit==============

Added this now that I'm  more clear on what you need.

```
select  Lpad(Name,Length(c1.Name) + LEVEL * 10 - 10,'-') Name 
  from Category c1
 start with c1.name = 'Category 2'
        and c1.id in (select c2.pid from category c2 where c2.name = 'Category 3')
connect by prior c1.id = c1.pid;
```

This will give you all branches starting with a Category 2 that have a Category 3 as the next child.

I've added another [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b32c/1) with an additional branch having a 2 / 5 relation so you can see it only returns the two 2 /3 branches.

Comment: I need to find by name "Category 2 and Category 3", but not find by ID.

Comment: Given what you said above, "Category 2 and Category 3" are not unique.  Any query you run using name is going to return all matches.

Comment: For example if there is a sibling node to Category 1 (following your above pattern) it would be named Category 2 and that node would have a child of Category 3.  So you would get both sets in a query.

Comment: I need to find all nodes of "Category 3", which has a parent "Category 2". I can find this nodes to using search in `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH()`, but it is bad decision.

Comment: Is your above data FIXED and PERMANENT?  Meaning this is the actual production data and it will never change.

Comment: sqlfiddle is back up.  take a look at the link in the answer.  Then look at  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0c6b/4 to see how I've expanded your possible data set.  Then look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0c6b/7 to see how using the names with "Category 3", which has a parent "Category 2" will still not get you the data you're looking for.

Comment: Data can be modified. As in 2 example is good, but only need to use 2 name for searching (+Category 3).

Comment: so you want all branches on the tree that have a 2 / 3?  Because in my example there are 2 different branches that will be returned.  One ends with 4 and 5 the other with 14 and 55.  Look at the last fiddle to see what I mean.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0c6b/7

Comment: I understand. I want all branches on the tree that have a 3 AND 2 as a parents.